# Nautilus/Caja Script to "Extract Here" Selected RAR/Archive(s) via Engrampa, File-Roller or Command?

Tags: scripts, nautilus, archive, extract, caja

I'm looking to create a file manager script to use in Caja (I used "Nautilus Script" in the title so people would understand what I was trying to accomplish) that will extract the selected archive (or multiple archives) to the current location. Preferably I'd like to specify Engrampa to do the extracting, but File-Roller, or even a command, would be fine (though I'd prefer to have the progress dialog pop up like when I extract them via "Extract Here").

Now, you may be wondering why I want a script for this when Caja has the "Extract Here" option in the context menu, just like Nautilus. The reason is that I've had great success assigning keyboard shortcuts to the scripts I use in Caja, so my objective is to be able to extract the selected archive(s) with a key-combo like Alt+X.

I have very limited expertise in scripts, but have managed to do some basic, but very useful, things like the following, which is open the selected image in Gimp, which I've assigned the combo Alt+I to:

```
#!/bin/bash
if mimetype -b "$1" | grep image; then
gimp "$1"
fi
```

I've used that same approach for a couple of other things that work great, like opening a folder with an image viewer, but trying to create a script for extracting the selected archive (specifically RAR, as that is what I most download) with Engrampa (**engrampa -h**) to the current folder, or even just the Unrar command (**unrar e**), nothing happens. I *think* the mimetype is specified correctly, I've tried it with **engrampa** minus the **-h** option to see if Engrampa pops up (all my working scripts have no option after the command), yet nothing happens at all. So, obviously I am doing something wrong with the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
if mimetype -b "$1" | grep application/x-rar-compressed; then
engrampa -h "$1"
fi
```

So I am calling on your expertise to solve this. While it's not *crucial*, as I can do it with a right-click, it would be great to get this happening, so I can assign a key-combo to it. I'd be happy with a script just for use with RAR files, though one that will extract any type of archive would of course be most welcome. And while I'd *prefer* a GUI app to do this, so I can see the progress, it's not vital. Many thanks in advance, and stay safe everybody!

PS: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, in case that matters. And I switched to Caja a week ago, as the Nautilus devs keep removing functionality.

Comment: You have to try Caja Actions package, it is available from *universe* pocket https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/caja-actions .

Comment: Yes, it is installed. Hence the ability to run all the scripts I already have. As outlined, it's not that I can't run scripts, it's that I don't have the knowledge to construct one that can extract a selected archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to Michal for pointing me in the right direction with the Caja variable! At first this didn't seem to work, then I removed the line:

```
if mimetype -b "$1" | grep application/x-rar-compressed; then
```

... and it worked as expected, with a visual progress indicator, and it can unpack multiple selected archives. So the script code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
engrampa -h $CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
fi
```

I've set **Alt+X** (for eXtract) as the shortcut/accelerator, and all is perfect!

---

**UPDATE**: I did come across one anomaly, being that when trying to extract an archive that contains a folder instead of files, it would throw up an **"Archive type not supported"** error message, and hence would not extract the archive (and I *did* try this on multiple archives that contained folders). However, after a while it came good (*mostly* - see below), so while I don't understand the how and why of those archives being treated differently to those containing individual files, and how that rectified itself, I'm not complaining!

(**Edit**: I've come across a couple of RAR archives containing a folder that still fail, and they are not corrupt or anything - they extract fine via right-click > Extract Here - so while that's still perplexing, and a tad annoying, I can live with having to do it that way for the occasional archive).

So I thought I'd share that info for anyone else who wants to use that script, which works for archives of any format (that is supported by Engrampa), for multiple selected archives, and also multi-part archives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `caja-actions` GUI for this.

> A graphical interface to create and edit your Caja actions.

Install it first `apt install caja-actions` then open.

Add new command "Extract Archive" under "Items List".

In the "Command" tab add:

```
Path: 7z
Parameters: x %F
Working Directory: %d
```

Save.

To know what "%F" and "%d" means click "Legend" button on the right side of Parameters field.

In the tab "Mimetypes" add all types for which You want to `7z` to operate in format "application/zip" or "application/gzip" (without quotes).

Comment: Thanks Michal for your answer... but there doesn't seem to be a way to assign keyboard shortcuts for Caja Actions (unless I am missing something?). And there already is an "Extract Here" context menu item, which would be quicker to get to than a Caja action for the same task. Hence asking for a script - that I could assign a keyboard shortcut to, which is what I would like to achieve. But thanks for your time.

Comment: @OzzyFrank Looks like You can't assign a key for actions created by "Caja Actions GUI" but You can do this when You create a script inside the `~/.config/caja/scripts/` directory. Then restart caja and open `~/.config/caja/accels` file and assign a key there for Your custom script.

Comment: Thanks again Michal - however, as I've outlined, I already know I can assign a hotkey/combo to a script, but what I don't know is how to construct the actual script. If you look to the original post, I have tried a couple of approaches for creating the script. but they are unsuccessful. So, in summary, I already know that the way to assign keyboard shortcuts is via a script, and I do know how to assign the shortcut to the script - what I don't know is the correct contents of a script to extract the selected archive.

Comment: @OzzyFrank You are very close with the script just use this `engrampa -h $CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` (note this may contain many paths, not only one) More info about all available environment variables for caja check [this link](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/blob/master/caja.pot#L6095).

Comment: I got that to work, and posted it as an answer, BUT I have hit one snag: while this successfully extracts archives with a file in it (and works with both RAR and ZIP), those that contain a FOLDER to be extracted produce the error "Archive type not supported". Any idea why that is and how to rectify it?

Comment: Michal this is really weird: it definitely wasn't working for archives that contained a folder, so I looked around for more info on using $CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS in scripts, tried something I found that totally didn't work for any archive, so reverted the code back to what it was, and all of a sudden those archives now extract successfully too! Can't make any sense of that, but I'm not complaining!!

Comment: Michal I spoke too soon, hahaha! STILL a couple of RAR archives containing a folder that wouldn't extract with the script, but extract fine via context-menu > Extract Here (so they're not corrupt). But before none of those did, so I count that as a win. However, if you know of any tweak to the code or variable that could fix this, feel free to let me know! Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @OzzyFrank Does this behavior have something to do with the type of the archive? The `engrampa` is only a "wrapper" for underlying archive programs...

Comment: -they were all RAR archives. I also tested on ZIP + TAR.XZ, but most of my archives are RAR, and the only difference was that those which wouldn't extract contained a folder rather than file(s) - and *none* of those would extract. Then I could extract those, except for a couple. And those holdouts extracted fine via right-click > Extract Here. So it definitely was strange, seeing as Engrampa had no problem when doing it via the context-menu, but I've downloaded a bunch more archives that unpack folders, and they've all been successful via script/hotkey since.

Comment: Cont:  So while my brain would like to understand the logic of what went on, it seems to be behaving now, so I'm happy with the result. Many thanks once again for your time and expertise!